# Two Expected value definitions of the geometric random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Ok so I'm looking at my book and it defines the geometric distribution to be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{n-1}$. My book says the expected value of a geometric random variable is $\dfrac{p}{q}$. It proves it using the probablity generating function for the geometric random variable. However, I have seen another expected value of a geometric random variable to be $\dfrac{1}{p}$. How are these two definitions related and when do I use one or the other?

Comment: PS to my answer.  These are not _definitions_.  They are propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric random variable is either

- The number of trials needed to get one success, in $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$; or
- The number of failures before the first success, in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

These are two different things.  You have to look at which of the two the book in question has in mind.  The first one has expeccted value $1/p$, where $p$ is the probability of success on each trial.  The second has expected value $(1/p)-1$ $=(1-p)/p$.

The second one has an infinitely divisible distribution; the first is not.

Comment: Oh I see so it's like the expected value of rolling a 6 is $\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{6}}$ and the expected value of someone shooting free throw shots given $p=0.6$ is $\dfrac{0.6}{0.4}$. But still I'm not seeing it because with the free throw you are measuring the number of success to but the formula is different.

Comment: @adam: with your dice throws, the expected number of throws to achieve the first six is $6=\dfrac{1}{1/6}$.  The expected number of non-sixes before the first six is $1$ less: $5=\dfrac{1}{1/6}-1=\dfrac{5/6}{1/6}$.